# Using Textwatcher causes weird issue in edittext search bar which's included at the top of adapter

Tags: android

In the application, I have a customized adapter which extends BaseAdapter. The adapter includes a header of two items, one of which is a search bar.
What I'm trying to do is to input text on the bar to search content on the listview, using my adapter. The challenge here is for Samsung Galaxy Note II, when I enter a character, the search bar shows what it is. However, for the second character I want to input, the bar shows nothing and it seems the previous character was cleared too. For any other devices, this works well. I have no idea of this. Can any guru knows the solution?

Here follows some snippet of ResearveHeaderAdapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent)
{
    View rowView = null;        
        HeaderItem header = mHeaderDef.get(position);
        if (header != null)
        {
            switch(header)
            {
                case REFRESHBAR:
                {
                    rowView = updateRefreshRow(convertView, parent);
                    break;
                }
                case SEARCHBAR:
                {
                    rowView = updateSearchRow(convertView, parent);
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {       
                    rowView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            rowView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        }
        return rowView;

}

  private View updateSearchRow(final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent)
{

        mCacheSearchView = mAllContentInflator.inflate( R.layout.search_bar_item, parent, false );
        mEditText = (ClearableEditText) mCacheSearchView.findViewById(R.id.topSearchBar);
        mEditText.setText(getSearchVarString());
        mEditText.setOnKeyListener(getSearchListener());
        mEditText.addTextChangedListener(getSearchTextWatcher());

        String search = getSearchVarString();
        String stxt = mEditText.getText().toString();

        if (getSearchVarString().trim().length() > 0)
        {
            mEditText.requestFocus();
        }
        mEditText.setEnabled(true);

    return mCacheSearchView;
}
```

Its subclass AllContentAdapter:

```
public class AllContentAdapter extends ReserveHeaderAdapter 
{
public AllContentAdapter(Activity callerContext,
        MediaObjectManager manager, boolean sensitive,
        MediaPolicy displayPolicy) {
    super(callerContext, manager, sensitive, displayPolicy);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super.appendHeaderItem(HeaderItem.REFRESHBAR);
    super.appendHeaderItem(HeaderItem.SEARCHBAR);
}

private static OnKeyListener mOnKeySearchListener = null;   
private static TextWatcher mSearchTextWatcher = null;
private static OnClickListener mOnClickRefreshListener = null;
private static String mSearchString = "";
@Override
protected String getSearchVarString()
{
    return mSearchString;
}

@Override
protected void setSearchVarString(String searchString)
{
    mSearchString = searchString;
}

@Override
protected OnKeyListener getSearchListener()
{
    return mOnKeySearchListener;
}

@Override
protected TextWatcher getSearchTextWatcher()
{
    return mSearchTextWatcher;
}

@Override
protected OnClickListener getClickRefreshListener()
{
    return mOnClickRefreshListener;
}

public void setOnClickRefreshListener(OnClickListener listener)
{
    mOnClickRefreshListener = listener;
}

public void setSearchOnKeyListener(OnKeyListener listener)
{
    mOnKeySearchListener = listener;
}

public void addTextChangedListenerForSearch(TextWatcher listener)
{
    mSearchTextWatcher = listener;      
}
```

So for the desired Activity, I called the `adapter.addTextChangedListenerForSearch(new TextWatcher())` which is like this:

```
((AllContentAdapter) mAdapter).addTextChangedListenerForSearch(new TextWatcher()
    {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
            String stxt = s.toString();
            ((AllContentAdapter) mAdapter).setSearchVarString(stxt);

                            // some handle code omitted...

            AllContentScreen.this.loadSearchFilter();// do some filter to search desired content
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {
        }
    });
```

The real result is that on Note II, when entering the second character, (Editable)s catches noting but empty string. Why?

Comment: This issue only occurs on Note II. In TextWatcher afterTextChanged(Editable s), the argument s merely passes in one character and for a second time while you input any character afterwards, s.toString() returns an empty string, which means even the first character disappears. It`s highly appreciated for any good advice.

Answer (score 0):

That's strange. I'm willing to bet that the Note uses a special InputConnection. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/BaseInputConnection.html

which produces custom Editables. You may want to set a custom Editable.Factory on your search EditText. Also, look at setting a SpanWatcher to monitor span activity, especially the composing spans. Here's an example from a [RichEditText library](https://github.com/kemallette/RichEditText) I created.

```
// Replaces the default edit text factory that produces editables
// which our custom editable and listener
public class TextFactory extends Editable.Factory{


    @Override
    public Editable newEditable(final CharSequence source){

        return new RichTextStringBuilder(source,
                                         mSpanWatcher);
    }

}
```

At the least, this will let you see a better picture of what's happening.

Comment: Also, here's an implementation of a better way to filter/search in case this fits your needs instead: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/2D-Graphics/ShowsalistthatcanbefilteredinplacewithaSearchViewinnoniconifiedmode.htm

Comment: You might be right as I was ever aware of this possibility. I'll try to figure out in this regard. And one more thing I'll take care of is whether this could affect the other devices.

Answer (score 0):

From debugging process, I probably found what problem was for this special device and solved this issue therefore. That is, when EditText.getText().getString() is not empty, we'll show the searchbar and setSelection(position). The 'position' here represents the searchbar. For any other devices, this works fine. For Note II, it seems that if we want setSelection for the position of EditText, this function will clear the entered text and return empty string. So the solution is to avoid this function by using a flag to see whether the EditText has empty string or not and do catch what is entered in the search bar.